# Extract Quantity and price from text

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have these data

```
CREATE TABLE #Items (ID INT , Col VARCHAR(300))
INSERT INTO #Items VALUES
(1, 'Dave sold 10 items are sold to ABC servercies at 2.50 each'),
(2, '21 was sold to Tray Limited 3.90 each'),
(3, 'Consulting ordered 15 at 7.11 per one'),
(4, 'Returns from Murphy 7 at a cost of 6.10 for each item')
```

from the Col i want to extract Quantity and Price
I have written the below query which extract the quantity

```
SELECT
ID,
Col,
LEFT(SUBSTRING(Col, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Col), LEN(Col)),2) AS Qty
FROM #Items
```

my difficulty is that i don't how i can extract the Pice.
Expected output
[image]

Comment: "Bought 2 3-fers @ USD4.50 per." "<Designated victim> bought a [710 cap](https://i.imgur.com/ecM3VS0.jpg) for $28."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were told already, that storing values within such a string is a real *no-no-go*.

But - if you have to deal with external input - you might try this:

```
DECLARE @items TABLE(ID INT , Col VARCHAR(300))
INSERT INTO @items VALUES
(1, 'Dave sold 10 items are sold to ABC servercies at 2.50 each'),
(2, '21 was sold to Tray Limited 3.90 each'),
(3, 'Consulting ordered 15 at 7.11 per one'),
(4, 'Returns from Murphy 7 at a cost of 6.10 for each item');

SELECT i.ID
      ,i.Col
      ,A.Casted.value('/x[not(empty(. cast as xs:int?))][1]','int') AS firstNumberAsInt
      ,A.Casted.value('/x[not(empty(. cast as xs:decimal?))][2]','decimal(10,4)') AS SecondNumberAsDecimal
FROM @items i
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT i.Col AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),' ','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(Casted);
```

The idea in short:

- we use some string methods to transform your string into XML, where each word is within it's own `<x>`-element.
- We use XML-XQuery's abilities to pick only nodes which answer a predicate.
- We use the predicate `not(empty(. cast as someType))`. This will return an element only in cases, where its content can be casted. Any other element is omitted.

The result:

```
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| ID | Col                                                        | firstNumberAsInt | SecondNumberAsDecimal |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| 1  | Dave sold 10 items are sold to ABC servercies at 2.50 each | 10               | 2.5000                |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| 2  | 21 was sold to Tray Limited 3.90 each                      | 21               | 3.9000                |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| 3  | Consulting ordered 15 at 7.11 per one                      | 15               | 7.1100                |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| 4  | Returns from Murphy 7 at a cost of 6.10 for each item      | 7                | 6.1000                |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
```

I'm sure you know that there are millions of cases where this kind of parsing will break...

Answer (score 1):

First things first: **DON'T** store things like that in a DB and expect to be able just "extract" data. I can give you a solution given the data you have, but it's going to fall down pretty quickly if anyone enters something silly, for example "Sold ice creams 1.50 each x 10" or "Bought 5 sorbets total 20".

What we will do is use `CROSS APPLY` in series to calculate the positions of each number.

```sql
SELECT
    ID,
    Col,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(Col, FirstNum, EndFirst - 1) AS int) AS Qty,
    CAST(SUBSTRING(Col, FirstNum + EndFirst + SecondNum - 2, EndSecond) AS decimal(18,2)) AS Price
FROM #Items
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Col) ) ) v1(FirstNum)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(Col, FirstNum, LEN(Col))) ) ) v2(EndFirst)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (PATINDEX('%[0-9.]%', SUBSTRING(Col, FirstNum + EndFirst - 1, LEN(Col))) ) ) v3(SecondNum)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', SUBSTRING(Col, FirstNum + EndFirst - 1 + SecondNum, LEN(Col))) ) ) v4(EndSecond)
```